# How to select the second Class element using jQuery working with Spock/Geb

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, spock, geb

I have done a lot of research to find out the answer for the following to no avail.

I have the following class in one `<div>` tag in the HTML.

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-navbar document-collapse pull-right' data-target='#document_521f7592388723hsjd73hd' data-toggle='collapse'>
```

And I have few more classes within few other `<div>` tags but they use the same class name.

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-navbar document-collapse pull-right' data-target='#document_521f75032f23104747ed753c' data-toggle='collapse'>
```

By Default, the first `<div>` is expanded and all the other `<div>` are collapsed. I need to be able to click on the second  and reveal thee other buttons and controls that are hidden.

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
expandOrderLink(wait:true)  { $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right:nth-child(2)") }
```

Is there a way we can look for all the class elements with the same name and choose the one we need (in my case the second one).

Also note that I cannot use any other attributes since have dynamic content with encrypted info (such as #document_521f75032f23104747ed753c)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: `$(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right').eq(1)` ??? But why using so many classes to target specific elements?!

Comment: Can you please simplify the selector. I cannot use anything else because of the same classes being used everywhere

Comment: This question is still outstanding. Can someone please answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is misleading in that you ask about how to select an element at an index with jQuery but in your code sample you're using Geb - I suggest you change the tile of your question. Geb's Navigator API is not compatible with jQuery, it's just [jQuery-like](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/intro.html#the_jquery_ish_navigator_api).

To select the second element in your example you can write:

```
expandOrderLink(wait:true)  { 
    $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right", 1) 
}
```

Check out the section on [indexes and ranges](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/navigator.html#indexes_and_ranges) in the manual.

You can also simply access an element using [subscript operator](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/navigator/Navigator.html#getAt%28int%29):

```
expandOrderLink(wait:true)  { 
    $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right")[1]
}
```

Comment: Hi erdi, Thanks alot for the answer to my query. It finally worked!! :-)I have been using a lot jQuery selectors in my tests and I didn't realise Geb doesn't support it completely. I will have to modify few of my selectors to be able to work with Geb.

Answer (score 12):

try something like this

```
  $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right").eq(1);
```

Comment: Sorry I get the following error: $("button.btn .btn-navbar .document-collapse .pull-right").eq(1)
|                                                          |
[]                                                         [] Both returned null

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work. If I remove .eq(1), it clicks on the first css and collapses the list. I need to click on the second CSS which is part of a different 'div' tag

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the second element always, then use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
  $("your classs").eq(1);
```

Comment: I have looked at .eq(index) before, it works only with the elements in the same tag. But as I mentioned the classes are across different tags and the eq is failing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right:eq(2)")
```

Comment: I get the following error: $(".btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right").eq(2)
|                                                 |
|                                                 []
[[[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (3d5b86d2-f14c-46c8-972d-f9bc9ff9c7f5)] -> tag name: html]] -> css selector: .btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right], [[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on XP (3d5b86d2-f14c-46c8-972d-f9bc9ff9c7f5)] -> tag name: html]] -> css selector: .btn.btn-navbar.document-collapse.pull-right]]